# Create and share table schema in confluence

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, confluence

I have three big databases which is mysql and each database has at least over 10 tables. I have to share those tables schema with other team and we just decided to use confluence, because we already using it to track development issues.
I wonder if there is any way to create table schema in confluence. If it is impossible then I would like to know other methods to create table schema.

Comment: If you use a third-party package, you have (1) learn that package's way of obfuscating SQL, and (2) learn the generated SQL.  I recommend typing the SQL manually.

Comment: Even if you insert tables into db, you won't have access to them unless you make a third party plugin.